# Axios catch error: Request failed with status code 404. Error while fetching post schema from my database

Tags: reactjs, axios, http-status-code-404, bad-request

```
Error fetching data: 
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
: 
"ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
```

I am trying to connect my server.js and App.jsx using api (axios module) and expecting the data to get saved in my mongodb document. But It's not happening instead I am getting an error.

here is my server.js code
`

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3001;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/yourDB', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB:', error);
  });

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  content: String
});

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

// API endpoint for fetching data
app.get("/api/posts", (req, res) => {
  Post.find({}, (err, posts) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error fetching posts:', err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    } else {
      res.json(posts);
    }
  });
});

// API endpoint for creating new data
app.post("/api/posts", (req, res) => {
  const { title, content } = req.body;
  const newPost = new Post({ title, content });

  newPost.save((err, savedPost) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error saving post:', err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    } else {
      res.json(savedPost);
    }
  });
});

// API endpoint for deleting data
app.delete("/api/posts/:id", (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;

  Post.findByIdAndDelete(id, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error deleting post:', err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    } else {
      res.json({ message: 'Post deleted successfully' });
    }
  });
});

// Start the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

`                                                                                                            here is my app.jsx code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Note from "./Note";
import CreateArea from "./CreateArea";

function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("/api/posts")
      .then(response => {
        setNotes(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      });
  }, []);

  function addNote(note) {
    setNotes(prevNotes => {
      return [...prevNotes, note];
    });
  
    axios.post("/api/posts", note)
      .then(response => {
        console.log("Post saved successfully:", response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error saving post:", error);
      });
  }
  
  function deleteNote(id) {
    setNotes(prevNotes => {
      return prevNotes.filter((noteItem, index) => {
        return index !== id;
      });
    });

    axios.delete(`/api/posts/${id}`)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <CreateArea onAdd={addNote} />
      {notes.map((noteItem, index) => (
        <Note
          key={index}
          id={index}
          title={noteItem.title}
          content={noteItem.content}
          onDelete={deleteNote}
        />
      ))}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axios needs not only the `path` but also the whole `url`.

Instead of only using `/api/posts`, please try to use something like: `http://localhost:3001/api/posts` which depends on your server domain and port.

Sometimes it is exhausted to add whole url every time when calling api. [Axios Instance](https://axios-http.com/docs/instance) would be a nice choice to simplify these steps.

Comment: I added `axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:4000";` to my code now error was resolved. Thank you